# What rationale was used to justify the VTC as Opinion-Based and how can we avoid using this VTC reason in the future?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, policy

**I'm a firm believer in quickly closing questions that need improvement — but I'm also a believer that the "Opinion Based" VTC reason is the least useful, if not completely useless, reason to close.**

Regarding https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/236410/40609, posted as the first question by a new user. It was quickly closed and almost as quickly deleted by the OP. Closed so quickly, that I was unable to post [available research pertinent to answering the question](http://www.hopesandfears.com/hopes/now/question/216619-will-to-die) before closure.

Am I complaining because I couldn't post that comment to help the OP? Honestly, yes. But I'm also complaining because the Opinion Based VTC reason is ridiculous. We all know it's ridiculous. And any question closed because of it probably deserves an internal review here on Meta to better understand why that VTC reason was used because, based solely on the results of a 10-second Google search, that reason was used by people who did not perform any research, but simply believed (I suppose) that no research could exist, and therefore only unsubstantiated opinion could result.

Although not alone, I for one have wondered a number of times what to do about the Opinion Based VTC reason:

- [A Plea for Consistent Close-Voting](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9643/40609)
- [How to make a "Fishing for Ideas" question fit on Worldbuilding Main](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8398/40609)
- [How best to deal with "what are you expecting?" questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7268/40609)
- [Phrasing questions such that answers can be objectively voted upon](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6936/40609)
- [How should we deal with inherently open-ended fishing-for-ideas questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6654/40609)
- [Is it possible to change the descriptive text for the POB selection?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6240/40609)
- [Magic is primarily opinion-based by definition, so what does a POB VTC mean?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5991/40609)
- [Clarification for new users: when is a "fishing for ideas" question on- or off-topic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5621/40609)

**Official Debrief:** Given that...

1. I quickly found an authoritative online resource that would answer the question and,
2. The Opinion-Based VTC reason descriptive text reads, "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations."

What rationale was used to justify the VTC as Opinion-Based and how can we avoid using this VTC reason (on a Stack that's defined in part by providing answers that can't be supported with facts or citations) in the future?

---

**Closures since this question was first posted:**

- [What kind of government would a race of sentient zombies have?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/236428/40609) should have been closed as "too story-based."

Comment: A user deleting a closed question and a question being closed are not the same, and that is not the close reasons fault.

Comment: @Topcode I did see some people questions deleting their question due to the negative reactions about said question. And this doesn't change the main point : the question was closed too hastily and not enough searchily according to JBH.

Comment: @Topcode That's not the question, either. I pointed that out because [WillK isn't wrong](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9765/40609), at least in spirit. We closed that question quickly, but for what appears to be a *bad reason.* The consequence as I started writing the post appeared to be the OP had abandoned the Stack (been chased away). My note at the bottom confirms that what he really did was try to circumvent the rules. But the premise is unchanged. I advocate closing quickly, but we need to be *right.*

Comment: I had to look through the link's name, to know what the question was about (can't read the deleted questions :) ). In case some are wondering about what it was, it was this : Is it plausible for one's own vivid imagination kill them?"

Comment: You're misrepresenting the question in the state it was in when it was closed. Instead of asking if someone's imagination could be harmful to them, they were asking "Can you kill someone with something that isn't real". I VTC'd the question around edit 4 when it was definitely inappropriate for this site.

Comment: @sphennings Thanks, I see exactly which question it is about now :).

Comment: @Topcode I rolled back your edits - they're materially wrong. If you're not going to ask permission to make a clarifying edit, stick to spelling and grammar. Thanks.

Comment: @sphennings That's a good point. It's likely that VTCs were collected all along the way. But I'm still adamant that we should start debriefing about *why* "Opinion-Based" was the most appropriate choice for a VTC reason. Heck, I'd rather people used "Community Specific Reason -> Other" and explained the problem than use a VTC reason that has so little meaning on our Stack. No one can reasonably conclude why it was used. Worse, now that it has been deleted, Community might start clearing out the flotsam so there's nothing left to analyze.

Comment: @JBH The final VTC reason is an aggregate of the 5 close voters. It is only there to help categorize the most prevalent issue. Perhaps we could add extra custom close reasons to better indicate site policy to people who don't pay attention to meta. Most of the time people end up punting and selecting something close enough. Given that the question had significant issues closing it was appropriate. Quibbling that people selected the wrong close reason seems to be moving the goalposts on this question.

Comment: @sphennings As you've surmised, my principal complaint is the OP is left with basically nothing to help them discern what went wrong. Unless Community is already cleaning up comments, none of the close voters left any explanation for their vote. I'd be all for additional close reasons that did a better job of reflecting Stack policies. I'm not sure I have the faith necessary that the Mods will make them. And nothing's stopping people from using the "Other" category with an explanation. I use it regularly.

Comment: @JBH Haven't I detailed the issue in the question? It was about Willk's lies at the start, followed up by the idea that they were more brainstorming than solving a specific issue, with two links towards the help-center *and* advises to clarify what they meant by "unreal" and who and from whom the crime was about.

Comment: @JBH so you said that it’s not the question, aka not your point, but editing it out is wrong. Ok then

Comment: @JBH You're all over the map with what you're talking about. Constructive comments when close voting, using the correct close reason, delaying closing questions, angry that you didn't get to answer a question that wasn't suitable for this site. It's hard to meaningfully engage with you when you keep changing the topic of the conversation. I'd like to be able to hear what you have to say and meaningfully engage with it, but currently you're making it extremely difficult.

Comment: @Topcode Among other things, you changed "comment" to "answer" which was false.

Comment: @JBH commenting an answer violates site rules, but alright, dig your own grave.

Comment: @sphennings Not really. My irritation is involved. What can I say. Tough bananas. But the question as posted remains unchanged: I think using Opinion-Based to VTC is a bad idea at the best of times. So, why was Opinion-Based used and how can we avoid it in the future? I understand your comment about aggregating the responses, but there still had to be a majority voting for that reason for it to be selected. So, if you'd care to answer: if you voted Opinion-Based, why did you select that and not another choice?

Comment: @Topcode The answer had been closed due to, IMO, ignorance of unresearched facts. But it had not been deleted. I was halfway through a "you might want to think about this" comment (the only possible solution to the problem once the question was closed, deal with it) when the OP deleted the post. You're not one of the vote casters, so unless you have a worthwhile recommendation for how to better deal with using the Opinion Based VTC reason... why are you here?

Comment: I've found that when I'm irritated about a bunch of things, attempting to talk about all of it at once inevitably leads to confusion miscommunication, and unsatisfactory results. Try to talk about one thing at a time and stay on topic. Your question above is not asking "why did people VTC POB instead of other close reasons?" Constantly shifting what's being talked about leads to confusion, frustration, and dismissal. That's great if you're wanting to stir the pot, but pretty inconvenient if you're wanting to engage in good faith.

Comment: @JBH We're here to answer all the non-POB questions that this site is intended for. This site promises that it isn't a discussion site, or a brainstorming site. It promises structure. And when there are answers that are suitable for this site I like answering them.

Comment: @sphennings All I've been doing is following our conversation. I'm more than happy to focus only on what my question asks.

Comment: @JBH “the only possible solution” no, that would be editing and improving the question.

Comment: @JBH - additionally, remember that once you post content anywhere on SE, it is public, and can be edited by anyone with enough rep. No permission is needed - and I think one of the edits improved the clarity of your post. The other one maybe wasn't as useful (the comment/answer edit)

Comment: Of course, judging by their behavior any effort spent explaining site policy or salvaging the question will have been wasted.

Comment: @Topcode I didn't need to edit or improve the question. The form that existed when I found it didn't deserve to be closed. But you're missing a point: the OP deleted the question in less than two minutes. Do you really believe my vote to reopen would have changed that?

Comment: @sphennings Yeah. That was after the fact. I began writing this post on the assumption that we'd chased away another new user. He did prove to be as determined as I, though.

Comment: @JBH “a point: the OP deleted the question in less than two minutes.” Which isn’t the fault of the close reason. “I didn't need to edit or improve the question.” You thought you didn’t, but the consensus was against that.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Sorry, I deleted my last comment. I've been following three conversations about the referenced question on Main. I didn't catch on to the fact that you're referencing edits made to this post. Sorry about that. Even SE doesn't allow people to edit without consequence and this Stack is more restrictive than most. I disagree that any of Top's changes were improvements.

Comment: @Topcode That could be true, but it's more likely false. People rarely return to Qs they've voted on to see if any improvements have been made and later voters too often trust that the people who have previously voted had good reason to do so. Sphennings directed me to the edit chain which shows that the OP was making changes, some better, some worse, so a blanket claim that the result was what everyone was voting on is unlikely to be true. But that doesn't change the premise of this post: The Opinion Based reason was used without anyone explaining why on a Stack where it's almost meaningless.

Comment: @JBH Edited questions automatically get entered into the VTRO queue. There's a system in place to reopen closed questions when their issues have been resolved.

Comment: @JBH - you may disagree that they were improvements, but remember the community is the ultimate arbiter of these, as posts are community property once you post them - the primary aim is to benefit the future community of visitors, and it is possible that will clash with your aims.

Comment: @JBH you can disagree with the current reopening system, however that is site wide and should be discussed on meta se.

Comment: @sphennings Yeah, OK... what edit do you think I should have made? I didn't see a reason to edit it. If I read the history chain correctly, the OP edited the question 7 minutes after L.Dutch cast the last close vote and deleted the Q 15 minutes later. Based on that, I visited the Q 2-3 minutes before the OP deleted the question. My research took a minute or two, and I type fairly quickly, so my window of opportunity to VTR was about 15+/- seconds. But... does the background leading to my post change my post? What about what I saw was opinion-based?

Comment: @RoryAlsop The community is NOT the ultimate arbiter of edits and never has been. That's why the rollback feature exists.

Comment: @Topcode How odd... my post doesn't say anything about the VTR process. Do you have anything meaningful to say about the question in the post?

Comment: @JBH You're mistaken, the question was deleted by it's author. It's also possible for there to be unsalvageable questions, and TBH I think that question was unsalvageable by 3rd party edits when it was deleted. Only OP knows what they want to accomplish so more often than not salvaging a question requires editing it to accomplish a narrow subset of the original question, which can only be done with knowledge of OP's goals.

Comment: @JBH your justification for your rejection of my edit does however which is related to the question. You make a good point though, this should probably be moved to chat as topic is shifting away from the intended one.

Comment: @JBH Users with sufficient rep are encouraged to make edits that they think will improve a post without conflicting with the intent of the OP. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: @sphennings What part of `It was deleted 3 hours ago by the post author.` suggests it was someone else? And every edit in the [edit chain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/236410/revisions) was made by the author. I think we're off-track.

Comment: @sphennings Are we still talking about the referenced question or are we talking about this Meta post? If the later, I believe the edits Top made conflicted with the intent of the OP.

Comment: @sphennings OK, I've been tracking too many conversations. You're correct that it was deleted by the author and I can see from my comment about timelines where I was not at all clear about who deleted the post. Indeed, I have always known the Author did it (I say so in this Meta post). I apologize for misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: If OP chooses to delete a question after editing it, that seems like something that is outside our abilities to prevent. Given the text of the question, as it was reviewed, closure was unarguably the correct call. Expecting the question to clear the VTRO queue in ~30 minutes seems incredibly optimistic, even if there was complete agreement that the question in it's final edit was suitable for reopening. Remember that we review questions *de novo* and consider whether the most recent edit is appropriate for this site, not just whether the one listed close reason has been resolved.

Comment: @sphennings Please don't forget my original premise. I was almost done writing this post believing that we'd chased away a new user via the worst VTC reason on our list when he/she popped back up. My goal isn't to stop people from deleting questions, but to minimize losing new users by providing better explanations for our actions. Note that I don't believe it's reasonable to assume a new user knows anything about the VTR process. From their perspective, the action was likely seen as permanent.

Comment: I thought your premise was "Maybe we should also do research before casting a VTC"

Comment: @sphennings Good point, I'll make the title match the post body question.

Comment: @JBH Now that you've slowed down a bit, consider re-reading my comments on trying to remain focused. I think you'll get a lot more mileage out of focusing on one single specific point than you have been by being distracted and all over the place.

Comment: Your last edit looks like a quick jab at your own question ^^. If you happen to decide to answer your own question for the story-based part, I'd like you to read again the [link](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened) provided by the story-based closure and to clearly define the terms to reach this outcome. Last time it seemed like you didn't manage to rationalise why something would "choose" over "being", especially in the context of whole organizations someone is creating or choosing to create.

Comment: The question that got closed is unavailable to users below a certain threshold: to make this a proper meta post I think it is important that that question is mentioned in your question. It might be somewhere in the comments, but I'm not going to sift through all of them.

Answer (score 2):

### Was the opinion-based close vote reason "ridiculous" for the question you read? Probably yes.

I am the first one to have voted to close, exactly for this reason. Wait, there's a contradiction, isn't there? Welp, **It's just that I voted to close for the 1st revision.**

I don't know what happened to the question after my vote, but knowing it leaped from "How can you kill someone with something that isn't real?" to "Is it plausible for one's own vivid imagination kill them?" implies there were big changes meanwhile. Therefore the close-vote reason is likely to be at least obsolete, if not the closure in its entirety.

Also note that because official closure reasons are not exhaustive and because they're chosen by the majority, they are explained very often nowadays. I do it every time, and if I didn't, I upvoted the comments that matched the closest the reason I chose. For this question, it was something akin to this :

> Disregarding the logical impossibility depending on how you look at it (Willk's lies is a neat example<sup>1</sup>), it looks more like you're brainstorming, something SE isn't really good at, [as per the help-center says](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). *[To focus on a more specific issue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*, perhaps start by giving *more* details about what you mean by "not real" and who and from whom the crime is about?
> <sup>I put in italic the words I'm not sure anymore, it's copied from my butterfly/goldfish memory .</sup>

### Was and is the opinion-based close-vote reason "ridiculous"? No.

And I mean both for the 1st revision and in general. If you wish for an official SE source, the best one I think is this one : [Good subjective, bad subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). But it's 12 years old now so likely outdated to the new norms and it's not exactly the way I think, anyhow :). I do entirely agree on this very sentence though :

> Most forums and chat rooms have a scale problem. As in, they don’t. The more people that join the discussion, the more noise each of those connections bring. So the forums get progressively noisier and noisier, and suddenly one day … **you stop learning.**

From my personal experiences in both forums and real-life as a tutor, the more you give to someone at once, the less they actually receive. There's a limit to how much someone is able to learn, if not even willing to learn in a information overloaded world ⚡.

As such, this site is a [lil' bit different from others : Ask questions, get answers, *no distractions*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour).  Well, this is the ideal, at least . Point is, the site is designed with that motto in mind, going from "game-like" mechanics like score to how and which questions are displayed to the readers. Opinion-based questions in which [every answers are equally valid](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) strongly lends towards distracting discussions and prevent clear categorizations. Unless you want page-long comments arguing on what wants the asker or disappointing feedback that it's not what they want "just because", it's a thing to part with, both sadly and for good measure.

In this question's case, the querent wasn't providing any context to what they wanted to achieve, they basically asked the question in title. This makes the question unnecessarily a brainstorm regardless if it was answerable or not, because it would have needed very subjective intrepretations in order to nail an answer, biases which doesn't represent the actual question behind. If I wasn't closing for opinion-based, I would have closed for either being too broad or lacking details, with a very similar advise at the end; Indeed, these two other reasons complemented opinion-based, as no clear goal was given : What's important to them when they want to kill someone that way? Is it efficiency, mass-murder, speed, sneakiness? Something else? What should be prioritized? And what is already existing, in order to determine by the opposite what can be answered?

### Subjectively

But most importantly -and that's where the objective part leave the stage for my viewpoint-, since they haven't showcased a choice made on the starting point and a direction, how can one reliably answer and not hinder their creativity ? Not giving anything highly suggests they're still in the stage of choosing than inducing, ie. brainstorm.

Issue is I don't know them, nor do I know their project -if they have one-, and so the choices that will attract them the most. Supposing that Willk's example is the correct interpretation, that the crime tool just needs to not be "material" or "physical", [giving the possibilities I could think of would inherently restrict the choice they would make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma). Yes, even if am -or was ?- able to reverse the chessboard most of the time. I would limit not because of rational thinking based from facts about the world, but because I will necessarily impose my viewpoint on what they should do from what *I*, the "expert at worldbuilding" would do. Problem is, I'm not an expert of *their* world.

I'm not here to restrict the end choice they are free to make, and I think anyone else shouldn't, either. It's a very quick-sand way of drowning one's motivation, their inner goal not being the same as the world they're creating. It's the most important thing, ever<sup>2</sup>. In other words, it's the most counter-productive way of helping someone build **their** world.

This is why I intimately think opinion-based is a valid close-reason. Are the official statement unclear or wrong? Yes, I do agree it's very misleading, and the help-center telling every answers are equally valid is a much better explanation. Does it mean it's unfit in its entirety? No for the above reasons.

It's annoying, but we have to compensate its usage with a comment explaining why. But remember it's like any other closure reason, wherin we need to give which timeframe the reason is valid in case of major changes, and just what exactly is the issue and what should be done to improve the question .

---

<sup>1 : Willk's example was a link to lies spread for the Covid epidemy, which in turn led to deaths. For them, it was something "unreal", but I contradicted saying that the fact in the lies don't exist, but the lies did, and it's the latter which killed people.</sup>
<sup>2 : For a complementing reference, the very last and most important objective of "The Art of Game Design" book by Jesse Schell ends with this : "Why do you do this?". My book is an old edition, but I doubt it has changed in the newer ones.</sup>